# How to compare current date with the previous date using triggers in oracle form?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracleforms

I am new to oracle forms & triggers and I am making a tax payer form in which I've made the following fields:

```
Tax_Code| From_Date | To_Date
```

Now I want to make a trigger that should check that the date which is being entered now does not lie between the date that has been entered before.

for example if there's an entry

```
001 | 01-JUL-2013 | 30-JUN-2014
```

then no one should be able to write any date between these previous entered dates.

Comment: Can I enter `002 | 01-JUL-2014 | 31-DEC-2014` or `003 | 01-JAN-2013 | 30-JUN-2013`? And what about `004 | 01-JAN-2013 | 31-DEC-2013`?

Comment: you can enter 002 and 003 but 004 is invalid because the 30-DEC-2013 lies between these dates that have been entered before.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to combine a couple of different triggers to do this...

1. Inside of a POST-RECORD trigger, you would need to add a call to the "post" built-in to send the new/updated record to the database
2. Create a WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD trigger that would query the database with something like this:

   ```
   declare
     cursor date_check_cur is
       select tax_code, start_date, end_date
       from   tax_code_table t
       where  :block.start_date between t.start_date and t.end_date
         or   :block.end_date   between t.start_date and t.end date;
     v_dates date_check_cur%rowtype;
   begin
     open date_check_cur;
     fetch date_check_cur into v_dates;
     if date_check_cur%found then
         null; -- Display some kind of error to the user that entered dates conflict with returned date range...
     end if;
     close date_check_cur;
   end;
   ```

The caveat to this solution is that you now need to be VERY careful about transaction state, as you have written (but not committed) data to the database.  This solution also does not consider the possibility of two users entering dates form two different screens.  That would require far more sophisticated database-level triggers...

Alternatively, you could do the enforcement (Using the same query referenced above) in PRE-INSERT and PRE-UPDATE triggers, which would not fire until the records are posted to the database, but that opens up the risk of entering a bunch of broken data that would need to be fixed line-by-line....